# Arabs recognise Hashems watchfull hand over Klal Yisroel

Tags: gentiles, eretz-yisrael, army-military-war, islam, faith-bitachon-emunah

I heard that recently an Arab officer claimed that they are competent with aiming their missiles but that Hashem is helping Eretz Yisroel

Does anyone know a source for this [online or other]?

Comment: I found [this](http://lazerbrody.typepad.com/lazer_beams/2014/07/allah-does-miracles-for-them.html), but I couldn't find a direct news source.

Comment: A source that some Arab said that, or a source he might be drawing on for his claim about Hashem?  The first seems off-topic (a question about current events).

Comment: http://www.srugim.co.il/83312-%D7%94%D7%90%D7%9D-%D7%94-%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%98-%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D?di=1

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://www.wnd.com/2014/07/their-god-changes-path-of-rockets-in-mid-air/#q6kJX8XtTcZlc2kr.99%22):

> It was a partial quote from Barbara Ordman, who lives in Ma’ale Adumim on the West Bank.
>
> Her exact quotation was: "As one of the terrorists from Gaza was reported to say when asked why they couldn’t aim their rockets more effectively: “We do aim them, but their God changes their path in mid-air."

Barbara Ordman is a Jew saying this in support of Israel, so at best this is a rumor that was printed in the press.

This is [the original](http://www.jewishtelegraph.com/world_8.html) op-ed from Barbara Ordman.